# How to set default font for Windows Notepad?

Tags: windows-7, notepad

From an unknown reason Windows Notepad changed its default font from its original, *unproportional (monospaced)* one, to the other, a *proportional* one.

There is no problem with changing it after launching Notepad, but it's annoying to do it *every time*.

Is there a way to reset / set the default font for Notepad?

Comment: Open notepad as administrator and make the changes you want, then close it, do the settings stick now?

Comment: @Moab, yes, they stick, but after restart (of OS) they are gone.

Comment: notepad save setting in the registry at: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad" but I have no idea why they are not being saved on restart.

Comment: Moab is right.
~ * ~
The registry settings are at `HKCU\\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Notepad`.
The font *type* is in `lfFaceName`.
The font *size* is in `iPointSize`.
If you watch the value in Base *Decimal*, the value `80` means font size 8.
The value `140` means font size 14, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new file in Notepad with the font settings that you want to be changed and one word in it and save it as temp.txt.
2. Delete the word in temp.txt to change it into a blank file that still has the changed font settings. temp.txt is an ordinary .txt file that can be used as a blank Notepad template that has a different default font.
3. Create a desktop shortcut to temp.txt and name the desktop shortcut *Notepad*. Clicking on the new *Notepad* shortcut will open a blank .txt document in Notepad.
4. When you save the changes in temp.txt remember to select *Save As....* whatever title you like, but not temp.txt so your temp.txt file will not be overwritten each time you save a new file in Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to the latest build of Windows 10 and the problem should disappear. I have tried to change the font in Notepad on my laptop, and my font settings keep to work after a system restart. My laptop is running Windows 10 version 1903 (build 18362.356).

Comment: I have Windows 7, and I don't want Windows 10. Moreover, there is no guaranty that if would fix my problem — I didn't this problem for many years But thanks for your effort.

Comment: That should be a bug existed for years. If you wouldn't like to upgrade to Windows 10, you can use Notepad++ instead. It's open-source and freeware.

Comment: No, it's not a bug, many years was it OK. I use Notepad++ (and other editors) for many years, but I need a Windows Notepad, too. Nevertheless, thank you for your attempt to help me.